# Configuring dockerized Keycloak by CLI commands

Tags: docker, command-line-interface, keycloak

I'm trying to configure a dockerized Keycloak server like creating a realm from CLI command in the Dockerfile:

```
FROM quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:11.0.0

# Create realm "realm_borrar" on keycloak
RUN /opt/jboss/keycloak/bin/kcadm.sh create realms -s realm=my_new_realm -s enabled=true -o --server http://localhost:8080/auth --realm master --user admin --password admin
```

The result of `docker build -f ...` is:

```
Logging into http://localhost:8080/auth as user admin of realm master
Failed to send request - Connect to localhost:8080 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

If I run the container (created with the same Dockerfile but removing the RUN sentence) and I execute the same CLI command (kcadm.sh ....) it works.

What should be the proper way to config Keycloak in the Dockerfile?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example on how to do it for ubuntu...

1. At a terminal, run Keycloak as a dockerfile, e.g.:

   ```
   docker run --name keycloak -p 8484:8080 -e DB_VENDOR=h2 -e KEYCLOAK_USER=admin -e KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admin jboss/keycloak:11.0.0
   ```
2. At another terminal, run the CLI commands you need as exec commands for the container, e.g. for `kcadm.sh get realms` do:

   ```
   docker exec -it keycloak /opt/jboss/keycloak/bin/kcadm.sh get realms --server http://localhost:8080/auth --realm master --user admin --password admin
   ```

If you want to run everything on the same terminal, use -d (detach) on the first docker command.

For `create realms` using a file, map the directory of the file inside keycloack when running (mapping files directly should also work in theory) e.g.:

```
    docker run --name keycloak -p 8484:8080 -d -e DB_VENDOR=h2 -e KEYCLOAK_USER=admin -e KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admin -v host_abs_path:/cfg jboss/keycloak:11.0.0 
    #wait for keycloak to start...
    sleep 10
    docker exec -it keycloak /opt/jboss/keycloak/bin/kcadm.sh create realms --server http://localhost:8080/auth --realm master --user admin --password admin -f /cfg/my_realms.json
```

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, Keycloak must be running and it must be connected to the DB, when you want to add realm. And that's not a case when you are building Docker image. It can be done only when container is running, so use startup scripts.

https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/keycloak/

> A custom script can be added by creating your own Dockerfile:
>
> FROM keycloak
> COPY custom-scripts/ /opt/jboss/startup-scripts/

Comment: I guess that startup scripts will be executed any time the container is initialized so restarting it the configuration would be repeated, i. e. if the script creates a realm and I stop and restart the container the realm would be created again (suposing that keycloak allows the same realm).

Comment: @PacoAbato so why you don't include also business logic into the script: create realm only if realm doesn't exist

Comment: I have just read that containers should not be stoped and resumed but destroyed and again created for new https://stackoverflow.com/a/62563081/2595658 I will try your solution in a while, thanks.

Comment: I managed to execute startup scripts but commands like `/opt/jboss/keycloak/bin/kcadm.sh create realms ` keep on failing. I guess I must use embedded commands like `/subsystem=keycloak-server/:write-attribute(name=web-context,value=myContext)` but can't find which attributes would do the work for adding a realm for example.